# How to unite together 2 model fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaclass

I have 2 fields in my model class

```
class A(model.Model):
    field1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='path', null=True)
    field2 = models.URLField(null=True)
```

I need to unite so that if first field is full, second field can't be filled. And vice versa.

I try to create Meta class in class A with field unique_together:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (field1, field2)
```

but in that case, both field can't be empty and both can be full. But I need that just 1 of fields must be full.

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything at the model level to enforce this. Why not just enforce this at the form level? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: At this moment I do it at the view level, but I would like to do this at the model level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize save() method in you A model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.field1:
        self.field2 = ...
    if not self.field2:
        self.field1 = ...    
    super(A,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```